# How to apply python methods within a Class?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-3.x, attributeerror

How can I use 'default' methods for example: `string.lower()` within a class?

This is the error I get:

```
result = text.lower.replace(string.punctuation, ' ').split(' ')
AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one more set of `()`

```
result = text.lower().replace(string.punctuation, ' ').split(' ')
                   ^
```

Comment: I added the braces but I still get the error. result = `text.lower().replace(string.punctuation, ' ').split(' ')
AttributeError: MyClass instance has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: What is `text`? Is it a `str`? Can you show your call to `isWordIn`?

Comment: text is a string like a news headline `'Koala bears are soft and cuddly'`- `class TitleTrigger(WordTrigger):
    def evaluate(self, text):
        return(self.isWordIn(text))`

Comment: @Omicron You didn't add the `()` or you wouldn't have received the error "...has no **attribute** 'lower'". It would have said something about not having the correct **method**.

Comment: Also editing your original post invalidates the answers below it, even though this was exactly the source of your problem.

Comment: I fixed the '()' mistake and the error is exactly the same!. So I it was not really the solution. Should I write a new question?

Comment: Yes, please write a new question. Before you do this please verify that `text` is in fact a string. Use `print type(text)` in your method and check the output.

Comment: `text` was actually an object not a string. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

`()` is missing in `lower` method.

`a.lower` will return function object.

e.g.

```
>>> a = "ABCf"
>>> a.lower
<built-in method lower of str object at 0xb7047ac0>
>>> a.lower()
'abcf'
```